# How to create notification on a webpage

Tags: python, django, backend

This question is related to backend development. I am an intermediate-knowledge university student working in this field.

For my project, I am developing a website that alerts the user if something's missing from its place. For example, a valuable thing is placed under the scrutiny of CCTV. Then I detect the object using Image processing and as the thing is gone, I want to raise an alert.

I have done Image processing and am able to detect the presence/absence of the object on my local machine. I want to deploy such a thing on the server for end-consumer usage.
But then how to do this on the server because then two things need to be done at once, the video needs to be continuously processed, and when there is an alert, a notification should be kept in the notification feed (just like any social media platform), while also continuously monitoring the video.
I am familiar with Django.

In a nutshell, I want to understand how social media websites, also sometimes show notifications while we are scrolling the feed. How two things are managed at one time?

Thank you for the help.

Regards.

Comment: To handle the initial request, a Django asynchronous queue is required. This would allow for an immediate return. The client would then periodically poll the server every N seconds to check for the result. On the server side, when polled, you must check if the job has been completed (e.g. by checking the database for a result entry or something)

Comment: Thanks for the term @AlanSTACK. I searched for it and it seems that was what I will possibly require. I will get through it to confirm whether it really suits the job and if not, I will again reach out to you here. Thanks.

Comment: You can use WebSockets, which allow for real-time, bidirectional communication between the server and client. The image processing can be run on the server and the results can be sent to the client through the WebSockets. The client can then update the notification feed in real-time as new alerts are generated. You can use the Django Channels library to handle WebSockets.

Comment: @Nova, since I am quite a novice, I just want to confirm it once. Here by the server, you mean the hosting service, and by the client you mean the endpoint accessing the website, right? How can I make the hosting service process Video frames or Image processing always? It is Video processing (not image) that is real-time fetched from a CCTV.

Comment: Yes. By server, I mean the hosting service where your website is deployed. By client, I mean the end user who is accessing the website.

On the server, you can set up a service that continuously captures video frames from the CCTV and performs image processing on them. The results of the image processing can then be sent to the client in real-time through WebSockets.

And to ensure that the video processing is always running, you may need to set up the service as a background task or daemon that is automatically started whenever the server is rebooted.